# Visual Studio 2010 hangs on "Configure Remote Desktop Connections" for Windows Azure

Tags: azure, freeze, visual-studio-2010

When trying to access the settings for the remote desktop connections in my Azure project Visual Studio 2010 SP1 hangs until forced to close. I installed the new Azure SDK (november 2011) and the problem persists. The problem occurs either by checking the box or clicking "Settings.." in the Publish window (I tried to post a screenshot but unfortunately my reputation is too low.. ;-) )

I enabled the logging in Visual Studio and got the following entries:

```
<entry>
    <record>326</record>
    <time>2011/11/15 06:55:14.972</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{8FF02D1A-C177-4AC8-A62F-88FC6EA65F57}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>327</record>
    <time>2011/11/15 06:55:14.972</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Unexpected system error mode before loading package [Visual Web Developer Project Persistance Package]</description>
    <guid>{8FF02D1A-C177-4AC8-A62F-88FC6EA65F57}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>328</record>
    <time>2011/11/15 06:55:14.972</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Web Developer Project Persistance Package]</description>
    <guid>{8FF02D1A-C177-4AC8-A62F-88FC6EA65F57}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>329</record>
    <time>2011/11/15 06:55:14.988</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{8FF02D1A-C177-4AC8-A62F-88FC6EA65F57}</guid>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\*\webdirprjui.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>330</record>
    <time>2011/11/15 06:55:14.988</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Web Developer Project Persistance Package]</description>
    <guid>{8FF02D1A-C177-4AC8-A62F-88FC6EA65F57}</guid>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

I'll be happy to provide more information if it's helpful.

Comment: This might not really add much to the table but I had the exact same problem with vs2012. Cant for the love of my life remember what i did to fix it. Think the problem occured when I changed something in the settings while fixing something with the certificates. From here the logic goes something like "Trying to read the certificates it hangs". Its the best I've got rightnow, maybe I got time to look it up this weekend when working on that project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated what was my problem and solved it. Steps:

```
1.Add a certificate. 
1.1 In the web-role project, open the configuration file under Roles and then select Certificates in the left menu. 
1.2 Click Add Certificate. (just leave it as it is created). 
1.3 Save. 

2. Try to open Remote desktop configuration. 
2.1 Visual Studio hangs. 

3. Solve it. 
3.1 Restart Visual studio.(Always as administrator).
3.2 Remove the certificate. 
3.3 Try to open Remote desktop configuration.
3.4 It should now work. Well.. It does for me.
```

Comment: Haven't experienced this issue in a while. It disappeared for me when I installed VS2012. I however tried your solution on my old installation and it worked like a charm. Hope it helps someone else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Really need more information to troubleshoot this.  Can you capture a hang dump when this happens and open the dump and let us see the callstack that is hanging?

You could also try running procmon and procexp to see if you see any errors in them:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653